# STCollapseTableView in iOS Objective - C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am getting this error while running in iOS 10 version but, not getting an error in less than ios 9 version.

Below is the image where get the error.

Error occurs when going back to the previous Viewcontroller. Error not occur when going to the forward view controller.

I am using STCollapseTable.

[image: error Image]

Comment: enable the zombies and check once

Comment: ***[Table_Name retain]: message sent to deallocated instance***, I am getting this error. How can I solve it?? and thank you @Anbu.

Comment: it means your STCollapse Tableview memory deallocated ,

Comment: when you faced this , navigate from one VC to another or else

Comment: How can I keep allocate?. It's working fine in iOS 9 and not working perfect in ios 10. Can you please suggest me to solve this error. Thank you.

Comment: when you faced this , navigate from one VC to another or else

Comment: but i am using *** [[self navigationController] popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];*** Code. I want to go back to the previous viewcontroller. it's work's perfect when I go forward.

Comment: thats what I wanted, got it

Comment: can you show some additional code related to this  `[[self navigationController] popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];` forward does not a problem stack will be available

Comment: but when i go back it's show's error. that's the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151023/discussion-between-anbu-karthik-and-aashish-bapodra).

Comment: Thank you, Anbu.Krathik for the help :).

Comment: its ok my bro, if you send the project i will debug, its okay carry on

Comment: Sorry, I already told you the reason bro. Thank you for giving the precious time. if You found any thing in code  let me know.

Comment: Andu bro finally solve it ;)

Answer (score 0):

I get the answer of my question just remove that thing from the view like as below :
Write in ViewWillDisappear method:

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
            [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
            [view_name removeFromSuperView];
}
```

Remove whatever retain in the console.

Another answer also work's when you not create `IBoutlet STCollapseTable *xyz`. Just create simple `IBOutlet UITableView *xyz`;

then write below code :

```
  -(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
            [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
            xyz.delegate = nil;
xyz.dataSource = nil;

    }
```

The second method suggested and help By Anbu.Kartik. Thank you bro.

Comment: ensure once it does not affect anywhere

Comment: Yes, Anbu bro i checked in iOS 9 And iOS 10 too. According to me removing the retain view is best.

Comment: Your answer also work's now anbu bro ;) . Your Help not gone waste see.

Comment: ha ha ha, dont forget to set the delegate = self, whenever your views become active

Comment: yes, two code delegate = self and dataSource = self too.